# How to use OR in Rails 4 ActiveRecord named scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have `course` and `category` models in my project. `Course` has many `categories` and `category` has many `courses`.

In `course` model, I have a scope `:search_by_category` that will take in a name of category, and find the course where the course's category name is equal to the name.

```
scope :search_by_category, -> (name){
  joins(:categories).where('categories.name = ?', name) if name.present?
}
```

The scope works fine if I have a single name. But when I have an array of names, it breaks, because `where('categories.name = ?', "Some name", "Some other name", "Some more name")` is an invalid SQL syntax.

After I experimented with rails console, I find that I need to use OR.

e.g.

```
where('categories.name = name[0] OR categories.name = name[1])
```

How can I rewrite my scope to achieve this, or are there any other ways that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
array_with_names = ["Some name", "Some other name", "Some more name"]
where('categories.name in (?)', array_with_names)
```

If you want use `OR` operator, make array with names and use `*` splat operator:

```
array_with_names = ["Some name", "Some other name", "Some more name"]
where('categories.name = ? OR categories.name = ? OR categories.name = ?', *array_with_names)
```

But i think this useless.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Also, for anyone in a similar situation, I had to add a chain in my controller, `.includes(:categories)` to avoid double counting.

Comment: you should use [`.references(:categories)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) with `.includes(:categories)` in `Rails >= 4`

Answer (score 1):

Use Rails syntax for this. ActiveRecord will automatically detect you are using array and will construct proper SQL syntax for you (whether to use `IN` or `=`).

```
scope :search_by_category, -> (array_with_names){
  joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: array_with_names })
}
```